# all Keys and Objects from a NSDictionary to a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I've got a NSDictionary and I'd like put all of it's objects and keys into a NSString, so that I can finally display them in a label like this:

key1: object1

key2: object2

key3: object3

...   ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build the string and then set it to the labels text.

```
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [myString appendFormat:@"%@ : %@\n", key, obj];
}];

self.label.text = myString;
```

### Note

The docs ([String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)) for the `%@` format specifier state:

> **%@**
> Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise. Also works with CFTypeRef objects, returning the result of the CFCopyDescription function.

So if these are your own custom objects in the dictionary you will most likely need to override the `description` method to provide more meaningful output

## Update

You mention that you need your output sorted by keys - dictionaries are not ordered so you will have to do it differently - this example assumes that your keys are strings

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    [myString appendFormat:@"%@ : %@\n", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]];
}

self.label.text = myString;
```

Comment: it seems you should add \n to the end of your format as in his example there was key-value par for each line

Comment: For me as a beginner this looks quite fancy, but it already kinda does what I need.

Comment: Awesome. the \n did the trick :) ...but how does this function sort the keys? In my case I have Dates as Strings and I'd like to to have them from past to recent.

Comment: In three words: you are AWESOME. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
for(id key in [dictionary allKeys])
{
    id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"%@ : %@", key, value);
}
```

Comment: Since you are using %@, you don't need to call the description method manually. Edit: Upvoted for quick fix :)

Comment: When you use fast enumeration with dictionaries, the objects you iterate over are the dictionary's keys. So, you don't need the call to `-allKeys` in your `for` loop. Just say: `for (id key in dictionary) ...`.

Comment: It's awesome how fast you guys are! Erm, but how can I display what is a NSLog in your code as a Sting that I can than put into a Label?  (like: [label setText: stringX];

Comment: ...what I mean is to create just one Label which then contains all entries from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *row;
for (id key in dictionary) {
    row = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]];
    // do something with your row string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam trying to append two time values from my TCTime object and display in label, even though I added "\n" towards the end it is printing only the first value but not the second value.

_feedTimes is NSArray.

```
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

TCTime *time = _feedTimes[indexPath.row];

[myString appendFormat:@"%s : %@\n", "Time 1 ", time.Time1];

[myString appendFormat:@"%s : %@\n", "Time 2 ", time.Time2];

self.label.text = myString;
```